# Is there a way to initialize an array or slice of bytes to zeroes in Zig?

Tags: arrays, byte, slice, zero, zig

Apparently Zig used to provide this feature in an easy way, but it was removed in [`6a5e61`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/commit/6a5e61acd117277eb2f943f5bc02ff7043542d4b).

What is the recommended approach now for when such a behavior is needed? To manually iterate through the array/slice and set all bytes to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std.mem.zeroes`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem.zeroes). Or use [`@memset`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#memset).

For example:

```
var a: [10]u8 = undefined;
@memset(&a, 0);
// or
// var a = std.mem.zeroes([10]u8);

std.log.info("{any}", .{ a });
```

This prints:

```
info: { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

as of Zig 0.11 (dunno when this was introduced), you can use the pattern repeat operator `**` like so:

```
const array_of_zeroes = [_]u32{0} ** 10;
```

This works with more complicated contents, too:

```
const things = [_]Thing{Thing.init()} ** 10;
const text = "ab" ** 15;  // ababababab...
```